# Add a label to each density line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make density graphs to compare the data distribution pattern. So I make the command like below.

```
graph<-ggplot (data=data1, aes (x=grain_weight) + geom_density() + geom_density (data=data2, aes (x=grain_weight) + geom_density (data=data3, aes (x=grain_weight) + labs(title="Distribution") + labs (y="Frequency") + labs(x="Grain weight")
```

1) Now, I'd like to distinguish each graph, adding a label or making color on legend. How can I do it?

2) I'd like to adjust X-axis from 0 to 150. How can I do it?

3) I'd like to make the background color as a white. Could you help me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Your question is too broad (you're asking three different things). Please go through [official docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html). Figure #4 answers 2 of your questions.

Comment: Dear. PoGibas~ Thank you so much!!! I'm a beginner in R so I'm not familiar with how to ask what I'm curious. Thanks to you, I solved my second question. Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, could you let me know how to add a name (data1, data2, and so on) on each graph in order to distinguish each graph. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be enough?

```
graph<-ggplot () +
       geom_density(data=data1, aes (x=grain_weight), col = 'blue') +
       geom_density (data=data2, aes (x=grain_weight), col = 'red') +
       geom_density (data=data3, aes (x=grain_weight), col = 'yellow') +
       labs(title="Distribution") +
       labs (y="Frequency") +
       labs(x="Grain weight") +
       xlim(c(0,150)) +
       theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! it really helps me~ I really appreciate!!! By the way, do you know how to add a legend to know blue graph is for data1?

Comment: geom_text(aes(label = c('data1','data2','data3'), ymax = 10000), position = "stack", vjust= 1, col = 'black')

Answer (score 0):

You can do a review of `ggplot2` documentation and examples and may be also for `dplyr` package. The easy way for me is mutating your `data.frames` adding a new col with the name of dataset. In this example I will use `dplyr::bind_rows()` function to combine all data.frames into one and adding a column with an id for each data.frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#some dummy data for this example
data1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 5, 1))
data2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 3, 4))
data3 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 2, 3))

# Combine the data.frames into one 
all.data <- bind_rows("my data1" = data1, #you can use the name what you want to replace "my data.."
                      "my data2" = data2, 
                      "my data3" = data3, 
                      .id = "Dataset")    # the name to identify each data.frame
ggplot(data = all.data, 
       mapping = aes(x = x,
                     color = Dataset)) +  # the `color` argument inside aes() is 
                                          # to map each group of data
  geom_density() #whatever geom you want to plot
```

For more powerful use of ggplot2, I recommend read the [function reference of ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/), [ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis (Use R!)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/331924275X) and [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Ggplot2](https://leanpub.com/hitchhikers_ggplot2)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really appreciate!!! This is what I wanted to know!!! thanks again!!!